# Check if string starts or ends with specific letter - java

Tags: java

I have a little problem checking if a string have a letter in it. Right now, i have a server/client situation where the server sends back a command to the client.

That command can be:

```
RM20 B
RM20 L
RM20 I

RM20 A "User input"

RM20 C
```

How do i check the letter if its a B, L, I or A or C??

Right now i made this code:

```
if ((fromServer.startsWith("RM20 A"))) {

else if ((fromServer.startsWith("RM20 C")))

else {

}
```

does this work? or will the if statement and else if statement be the same? i can't use ends with, because the RM20 A have an input in the end which can be alot.

is there a way to check whats in the middle. when you get, lets says

"RM20 A 123213124" as a String?

Comment: Yes, those lines of code do what you think they do, assuming that `fromServer` is a String containing a line similar to your examples. You could also check the 6th char of the string (`charAt(5)`), or use a pattern or regex.

Comment: If the prefix has a predefined length, such as 5 in your case (`RM20 `), you can use `fromServer.charAt(5) == 'B'`.

Comment: You could also use fromServer.charAt(5) to check just that letter.  By the way, your else needs curlies: if (bla) { } else if { } else if { } else { }

Comment: I know it needs curlies ;D it went a little fast.. but, mostruash made my day, using fromServer.charAt(5) == 'B' works perfect, alot better that what i have :P

Comment: Yes KEYSER, you also said it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only use the `startsWith()` test for the "A" command input, since that is the only one that has an arbitrary ending. The other commands have exact values, so you should use an `equals()` test for those. This way, you can reliably catch errors (e.g., "RM20 B xyz").

```
static final String A_COMMAND_PREFIX = "RM20 A ";

.
.
.

if (fromServer.startsWith(A_COMMAND_PREFIX)) {
  // Process user input
  final String userInput = fromServer.substring(A_COMMAND_PREFIX.length());

} else if (fromServer.equals("RM20 B")) {
  // Process B command
} else if (fromServer.equals("RM20 L")) {
  // Process L command
} else if (fromServer.equals("RM20 I")) {
  // Process I command
} else if (fromServer.equals("RM20 C")) {
  // Process C command
} else {
  // Handle unknown command
}
```

*I assume you have already determined that `fromServer` is not null.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your format is something like:

```
 <RM Code> <Letter> <Numbers> <Anything else>
```

Then you could do:

```
 String[] values = input.split(" ");

 if(values[1].equals("A")) {
     // Code for A.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to capture different groups. The `String regex` expression captures any word character up until a space. Then it captures any letter a-z or A-Z. Then, if there's a space and some other input, it captures that and uses it.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class test {
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws java.io.IOException {       

        String regex = "(\\w*) ([a-zA-Z])( (.*))?";

        String str1 = "RM20 A";
        String str2 = "RM20 B";
        String str3 = "RM20 C this is a user message.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher match1 = pattern.matcher(str1);
        Matcher match2 = pattern.matcher(str2);
        Matcher match3 = pattern.matcher(str3);

        String a;
        while (match1.find()) {          
            a = "Group 1: " + match1.group(1) + "\nGroup 2: " + match1.group(2);  
            System.out.println(a);        
        }  

        System.out.println();

        while (match2.find()) {          
            a = "Group 1: " + match2.group(1) + "\nGroup 2: " + match2.group(2);  
            System.out.println(a);
        }   

        System.out.println();

        while (match3.find()) {          
            a = "Group 1: " + match3.group(1) + "\nGroup 2: " + match3.group(2) + "\nGroup 4: " + match3.group(4);  
            System.out.println(a);       
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
>>> Group 1: RM20
>>> Group 2: A

>>> Group 1: RM20
>>> Group 2: B

>>> Group 1: RM20
>>> Group 2: C
>>> Group 4: this is a user message.
```

---

You could also capture the letters/number in the input code:

```
    String regex = "([a-zA-Z]*)(\\d*) ([a-zA-Z])( (.*))?";

    String str1 = "RM20 A message thingy";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    Matcher match1 = pattern.matcher(str1);
    while (match1.find()) {          
        System.out.println(match1.group(1));
        System.out.println(match1.group(2));
        System.out.println(match1.group(3));
        System.out.println(match1.group(5));
    }
```

---

```
>>> RM
>>> 20
>>> A
>>> message thingy
```